# Aligning Two Matrix Tables in SSRS Based on Matching Column Names

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have two matrix tables in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) with identical column names. I want to align these tables one above the other in such a way that the columns match up perfectly. Is there a method or feature within SSRS that allows me to automatically adjust the alignment of these tables based on the matching column names, or do I need to manually arrange them?

Both the tables have different datasets with different queries. Column names are same but the data is different. Any insights or advice on achieving this alignment efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Table 1:

| Column A | Column B | Column c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 |
| Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

Table 2

| Column A | Column c | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 3 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 6 | Cell 5 |

Expecting the columns A,B,C in both the tables aligned.

As of now I have added a Column Display Order, which I'm passing to both the queries. But is there any better way in SSRS.

Comment: Sorting the columns and manually setting the column width in the design as you are already doing is probably the best way. An alternative would be to union the two queries, include a 'tablename' column in the results and then use a single matrix that groups by 'tablename'.